# Load an image for canvas in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing an extension using the Pale Moon Addon SDK which is basically the exact same as Firefox's Addon SDK. I am trying to write an extension which notifies users when they have new messages on the social network deviantArt, but I'm running into a problem. I want the icon of the extension to change to show the number of messages the user has, so I created an empty document like this:

```
var {window: {document}} = require('sdk/addon/window');
```

Then I take that document and add to it an HTML5 canvas like so:

```
var canvas = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
```

So far so good, but the problem comes in when I try and add an image to that canvas. It says that Image is not defined.

```
if (is_core) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        image = ctx.drawImage(img, 6, 30, 32, 32);
    }
    img.src = self.data.url("h_core-status.png");
```

The problem, of course, is that I havn't loaded any module containing the Image object I need to create in order to add it to the canvas. However, I need that canvas to dynamically generate the icon for the extension. I considered adding a hidden iframe to the document and editing the canvas there, but it seems like a dirty solution.

Is there any Firefox Addon SDK module which contains an object like Image I can use, is there a better method to do what I'm trying to accomplish or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself by realizing that JavaScript's `new Image()` just creates an img tag that we then set the src to and when it loads, using that img tag in the canvas. So by doing this explicitly rather than using `new Image()` we can avoid problems with the Image object not being defined.

Just replace:

```
img = new Image();
```

with

```
img = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "img");
document.documentElement.appendChild(img);
```

Leave the rest of the code alone, it'll work.